# Calculating the normal between a straight line and a curved surface in three dimensions - python

Tags: python, math, 3d

For the time being I am asking for more conceptual answers than coding answers as I have been racking my brain as to how to do this and I am fairly new to python (I only properly started about 3 days ago but I have reached the point of being able to define the straight lines as classes and calculate dot products and what not using numpy arrays).

The problem I am trying to solve is as follows. I have a bunch of objects that I will just describe as a vector in my code as they are straight rigid cylinders. These cylinders interact with a non-smooth curved surface in three dimensions that I think I can define as a point cloud although I am still not entirely sure how I will go about this.

I need to calculate the normal to the surface at the point the vector describing the cylinder intercepts the surface. I assume I can just calculate when cylinder[x,y,z] - surface[x,y,z] = 0 in a few more words so I think that bit will be ok.

My main issue is that I am struggling to understand how best to create the 3D point cloud from a 2D image stack and then how to calculate the normal. When I have the normal I can envision how to calculate Euler angles and what not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the intersection normal, or how to create a point cloud from the image stack? Because the latter is much too broad for an SO question; the former is a lot simpler by contrast.

Comment: I need the answer to both but initially understanding how to define the surface as a point cloud is where I am stuck. Once I know that I think discussions with my supervisor and some reading of undergrad physics textbooks will likely be the way to go to understand how to calculate the perpendicular to said point cloud.

Comment: That is a *totally* different question to what your title says. Look into convex hulls and NURBS.